# ASP.NET MVC Custom Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I created a simple custom validation to make sure time entered is in a 12 hour format and the text input has a '99:99' mask set, so I will get:

12:00

The validation works great on the server:

```
     private ValidationResult ValidateTwelveHourFormat(string time, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(time.Substring(0, 1))
            || Convert.ToInt32(time.Substring(0, 1)) > 1
            || Convert.ToInt32(time.Substring(1, 1)) > 2
            || Convert.ToInt32(time.Substring(3, 1)) > 5)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

However, the same validation on the client does not behave the way I would expect:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal('timeformat', 'format');
$.validator.addMethod('timeformat', function (value, element, timeformat) {
if (value) {
    if (timeformat == "TwelveHour") {
        if (value.toString().substring(0, 1) == ""
                || value.toString().substring(0, 1) > 1
                || value.toString().substring(1, 1) > 2
                || value.toString().substring(3, 1) > 5) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
});
```

The client will correctly validate the first digit only.  So if I entered a 3, it would trigger fine, but not for any other positions in the string.  I threw some alerts in there and it seems to trigger the method when I enter a character into the text.  This behavior confuses me because I didn't think this would fire before the form was first submitted, only after.  Otherwise, the user would see error messages as they enter the form the first time and I don't believe that jives with the way validation typically works.

1.) Why isn't the client-side validating other character positions correctly?
2.) Why is the client validating when the form has yet to be submitted?

**Update**

1.) I used JavaScript's substr() as it acts like C#'s String.Substring().

For question 2 - I'm using Data Annoations with the mvc framework. Let's say I have a field set to be required. When I first enter that form, that field does not trigger validation on blur. I can enter crap, remove crap, but not trigger validation. That's why I'm confused. It seems to differ from the default behavior. I would think validation would be triggered after a submission attempt is attempted like the example I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

Javascript `String.substring()` works differently than C#. The second parameter is not the length, but the ending index. 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Question 2:

It usually validates `onBlur` too, in my experience.

Comment: javascript has `substr` though

Comment: @Esailija His code is using `String.substring()`, so I'm just explaining why it's not working as he expects. Check out the link.

Comment: Well I just wanted to put it out there that you could suggest it to him instead of trying to figure out what the end index must be in `substring`

Comment: For question 2 - I'm using Data Annoations with the mvc framework.  Let's say I have a field set to be required.  When I first enter that form, that field does not trigger validation on blur.  I can enter crap, remove crap, but not trigger validation.  That's why I'm confused.  It seems to differ from the default behavior. I would think validation would be triggered after a submission attempt is attempted like the example I mentioned.

Comment: @Esailija I see what you mean, now; `substr` would allow a more familiar coding pattern. In this case the ending index is easy, though; each item is only one char long.

Comment: @Beavis Client-side validation triggering for `Required` does seem a bit different, if my memory is serving. But I know I've seen some other client-side validation happen before the first submit attempt. I think. :)

Answer (score 0):

1.) My first answer was wrong; I need to look at it again.

2.)  Validate checks on keyup and on blur; you can set both of those as params in the options object

```
onkeyup: false,
onblur: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a Regular Expression Validator and then let IT worry about the client side code. You could use something like this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revTime" ControlToValidate="txtTime" ValidationExpression="[0]{0,1}[1-9]:[0-5][0-9]|[1][0-2]:[0-5][0-9]" ValidationGroup="x" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Not a valid time." />
```

and if you're using the AjaxControlToolkit, you can filter editing using their FitleredTextBoxExtender as follows:

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="fteTime" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtTime" FilterMode="ValidChars" FilterType="Numbers, Custom" ValidChars=":" />
```

Comment: This is MVC; those controls do not apply